# c#: Xamarin Email Sending returns email as HTML instead of rendering the actual layout

Tags: c#, email

So I am sending an Email in .net like so. I am receiving the email that I am reading from the file with the stream reader but it is returned as HTML code instead of the actual layout. Is there an attribute I am forgetting to set?

```
    public static async Task WelcomeEmail(string emailAdresse)
    {

        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(Constants.EMAILUSER, "Test");
        const string fromPassword = Constants.EMAILPW;

        var toAddress = new MailAddress(emailAdresse);
        string subject = "Wilkommen";


         string body;
        
        
         var assembly = typeof(Email).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
         string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
         Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("InteriorCircle.Resources.welcome_mail.html");
        
         using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
         {
             body = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
         }



        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = Constants.EMAILSERVER,
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };
        using (var txt = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(txt);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Should be : smtp.Send();  The formatted HTML is the body of the email

Comment: Actually, I just forget to set the body = isHTML to true.